# Laravel Fluent add select()s in separate places?

Tags: mysql, select, laravel, fluent, eloquent

```
//Earlier in the code, in each Model:
query = ModelName::select('table_name.*')

//Later in the code in a function in a Trait class that is always called

    if ($column == 'group_by')
    {
        $thing_query->groupBy($value);
        $thing_query->select(DB::raw('COUNT('.$value.') as count'));
    }
```

Is there a way to append or include a separate select function in the eloquent query builder?

The actual ->select() is set earlier and then this function is called. I'd like to add the count column conditionally in this later function that has the query passed into it.

Answer (score 16):

For future reference, you can use the **addSelect()** function.

It would be good to have in the documentation, but you'll find it here in the API: http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_addSelect

Comment: That link doesn't work for me, this one does: http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_addSelect

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you just insert the block you wanna execute as a function....according to the documentation on [Parameter Grouping](http://four.laravel.com/docs/queries) , you can do like so...by passing the Where a function...

This code below probably wont do what you want, but, its something for you to build off of, and play around with.

```
DB::table('users')
        ->where('name', '=', 'John')
        ->orWhere(function($query)
        {
            $query->group_by($value);
                  ->select(DB::raw('COUNT('.$value.') as count'));
        })
        ->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

`$thing_query->groupBy($value)->get(DB::raw('COUNT('.$value.') as count'));`

Also,if you are just trying to get the count and not select multiple things you can use `->count()` instead of `->get()`

Comment: That doesn't add the count to my other select queries, just returns it by itself